# Facebook ads for cheap LEGO : legit or scam?

Tags: sets, shopping, modular-buildings

Today, I spotted an ad on my Facebook feed for the website "winnerattop"

Someone commented on Facebook that this website is a mirror of "childtocoll".

[According to scamadvisor](https://www.scamadviser.com/check-website/childtocoll.com), both domains are only 4 days old, are hosted in France and have a Chinese owner.

The website headlines with "Black Friday sale", selling several popular LEGO sets at discounts of up to 80%.

For example, it sells the Parisian restaurant at no more than €27.20. See screenshot below.

[image]

Considering the owner being based in China, I'd be inclined to think that this is LEPIN being passed off as LEGO, but even for LEPIN those prices are suspiciously low.

Does anyone know what's up with this website?

And is it safe to assume there is zero chance that this is legit?

Comment: The site also appears to deceive users into believing this may be an official LEGO site by prominently displaying the LEGO logo in the top-left corner with no other identifying features for the website itself. I'm fairly sure it goes against many of The LEGO Groups brand guidelines. The social media and e-mail icons links are broken.

Comment: I just see another online website call 'znitans.com' selling a huge discounts on lego products too, with lego logo on the top left, with offer ends in 2 days xxx hours xxx mins, exactly as discribed. I will think it is a scam, too good to be true!

Comment: I see in the screenshot that the model number actually has letters in it instead of numbers for the set number. Another sign of scamming. 

Comment: And now everytime I attempt to access the site, they try to give me this "safer browser expirience" by downloading actual .exe files on my PC when browser extensions are NOT .exe files. It won't proceed unless I accept, so it's obvious that it's a scam.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I raised this same question on Reddit.

Two people over there pointed out that the website was actually selling pants instead of LEGO.

So I just tried to access the website through https://hide.me/en/proxy.

When I use their Dutch proxy, the site can't be loaded at all.

When I use their American proxy, the site is shop for pants.

When I use their German proxy, the site is shop for LEGO sets.

So I guess it could not be a scam more obviously.

Not only are they scamming people by "selling" items at ridiculous prices that they're never planning to deliver, but they're "selling" LEGOs in one part of the world and pants in another part on the very same website!

I've never seen anything like it.

Comment: Can we conclude from this that Americans spend more money on pants than Germans on Lego? ;)

Comment: @MichaelVerschaeve : It does seem to suggest that, yes 

Comment: Maybe they are trying to remind us about that fake TV show from the Lego movie about the guy who's always missing his pants 

Answer (score 10):

These scammer websites have been popping up for over a year on facebook.
Any money sent is lost. You will not receive even a Lepin set.

Use your common sense, how is this website supposed to make money with those prices?

Comment: And how does the name of the website even relate to what they’re selling?

Comment: I suspected as much. Still, I figured it wouldn't hurt asking the experts.

Answer (score 5):

I ordered a couple Star Wars sets from one of these facebook ads, and I was eventually delivered the sets.  I was very suspicious at first, but the same ad was still showing up after a couple months, so I decided to risk it.

Of course, they were the Lepin sets, and not the original Lego sets (although for the price that's what I was expecting.

Another important bit is that it took a looong time to ship. I received a tracking number, but it never updated.  I then threatened them in a support email to report them to PayPal if I did not receive the items.  I received a response and then a few weeks later I received my items (shipped through a Chinese delivery.  I don't know if it was a legitimate screwup or whether they only ship out items to customers that call them on it, but I got my items.

Would I be happier if they were truthful and shipped me the original Lego sets?  Of course.  But at those prices I was already expecting a Chinese knock-off, and these models are going to be built once and never disassembled, so they're never going to get mixed in with my real Lego sets.